# a, b = b, a как это работает?

Tags: python

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
if a > b:
    a, b = b, a
if b > c:
    b, c = c, b
if a > b:
    a, b = b, a
print(a, b, c)
```

Объясните дубу как работает a, b = b, a   я понимаю что это вроде как присваивание нескольких значений, но как это использовать и как это работает не совсем.

Comment: [Присвоение значений в Python. Различие способов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/614411), [Объясните функцию swap](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/901888). [Как быстро отсортировать 3 элемента?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/789961).

Comment: Смотри. Оно работает двумя наборами значений на момент старта строки. Т.е. вот программа идет, делает 1 строку, 2 и.т.п. Доходит до строки с этим =. Берет значения какие есть в а и в б. Выполняет действие. Т.е. не смотри на буквы, представь себе промежуточный шаг c = a, и d = b, а дальше делаешь a, b = d, c. Соответственно, a станет c (равному старому b), b станет d (равному старому a). А потом просто опускаешь промежуточный шаг.